# FDT and ATAGS support not compiled in - hanging ### ERROR ### Please RESET the board ###

Tags: linux, arm, embedded-linux, u-boot, intel-fpga

I'm following the [tutorial](https://zhehaomao.com/blog/fpga/2013/12/24/sockit-2.html) to install linux on SoCkit by Terasic.

This is my first time building a linux, so I am still learning. I was able to complete all the steps shown in the tutorial but when I try to boot it gives me error saying:

> Did not find a cmdline Flattened Device Tree
> Could not find a valid device tree

Now, I know the .dtb file is on the SD card and I can load it using the `fatload` command of u-boot. After I load the .dtb file and run `bootm` command I get the error saying:

> FDT and ATAGS support not compiled in - hanging ### ERROR ### Please RESET the board ###

I don't know where/how to enable this support. Could someone please help me with this.

Comment: This belongs on either unix.stackexchange.com or superuser.com. It's not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this particular SD card I am using wasn't getting formatted (partitions file system) properly on a virtual machine. I was running Ubuntu 14 on VirtualBox. I then formatted on a laptop running ubuntu and re-wrote the SD card. It booted up just fine!